# LXML itertree parsing tag information

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I have been searching around for answers, but I can't seem to find anything.
Using lxml to iterparse through xml, I have been trying to get data from within a tag.

For example, I have the xml:

```
<line number="0">Line 1</line>
<line number="1">Line 2</line> 
<line number="2">Line 3</line>
```

I need to be able to read < line **number="2"** >.
Printing out the tag only includes < line >.

Thanks!

Edit: rczajka answered my question (thank you!), but I was wondering: How do you do this abstractly -- without saying 'number'? The xml I'm parsing is gigantic, and I can't exactly scroll through all of it to see if there is anything hidden in the tags.

rczaika:
elem.items() will give you a list of all attributes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get information from an etree element you can do:

```
>>> elem.tag
'line'
>>> elem.get('number')
'2'
>>> elem.text
'Line 3'`
```

Comment: You are my savior. Thank you!
Do you know of a way to do abstractly -- without saying 'number'? The xml I'm parsing is gigantic, and I can't exactly scroll through all of it to see if there is anything hidden in the tags.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly, but `elem.items()` will give you a list of all attributes.

Also, try `help(elem)` :)

Comment: There it is. Fantastic, you have no idea how much frustration you saved me!